# Can't push to git over slow internet connection: ssh could not resolve hostname

Tags: git, ssh

I'm way out in the boonies right now and therefore can't access normal internet.  I need to push an emergency commit to a remote github repository (not github).  I do not have server admin rights, so I can't change anything server-side -- it's just a normal git repository.

I have a computer with a generated SSH key, which thus far I have been pushing changes with just fine.  Right now, I have a cell phone with 2G internet giving me a mobile hotspot to send data over.  It's exceptionally slow, but it's just a few lines of text, so it shouldn't be too much of a problem, right?

Upon trying to push my commit, I receive the message:

```
ssh:  could not resolve hostname [the address of the server I'm committing to]:  Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal:  Could not read from repository
```

I do not know if this is because of slow cell phone 2G hotspot internet or not.  I'm obviously able to connect to the internet just fine, and almost certainly make DNS requests as normal, since I'm able to open the server I'm committing to in a web browser just fine.   The error message shows *immediately* after I hit enter after "git push", as if it didn't even try to connect.

I'm running git on the lastest version of Ubuntu, in VirtualBox.  Until now this hasn't caused any issues at all.

Is this a known issue?  Would slow/cellphone wireless hotspot 2G internet be the source of the issue?  Without being able to access the server as an admin, is there anything at all I can do to push these small changes to the repository over this slow internet connection?

Comment: *ping* the hostname or *ping www.google.com* to see if connection is up

Comment: I can't ping it, in the VM.  ping:  unknown host [hostname].  However, I can still reach it by opening it in a web browser.  What's going on?  I can still ping it outside of the VM, actually.

Comment: Ah, that might be the problem.  google's not being reached either.  Gonna check the connection a little closer.

Comment: you have no DNS so the hostname can not be resolved to IP address. Try *ping 104.16.37.249* (is the IP of stackoverflow) or *nslookup*

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue.  nslookup is obviously not working either even though ping 8.8.8.8 or similar things work.  Any idea if this is something I can fix on my end, or just something with working through a 2G mobile hotspot that I can't help?  EDIT:  nvm, fixed it.  had to do some reconfiguring thing.

Answer (score 2):

So I fixed the issue.  Something was causing me to have DNS issues, possibly just some configuration issue.  Whatever it was, I put this in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

answered yes to the first one, no to the second one, and rebooted.  DNS worked again.  Perhaps it was a problem with the way I was connecting to the internet inside of the virtual machine, but whatever it was, the issue is no longer there.  I can connect to the git server now.